# uitoolbar with icons/text similar to uitabbar

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uibutton, uitabbar, uitoolbar

Ideally I want to use a UIToolbar but I want the icons at the bottom to appear as they would in a UITabBar meaning with icon for default and highlighted states and title beneath. I know I can drag a UIButton onto the toolbar and it will create a UIButton inside of a UIBarButtonItem, but I can't seem to manipulate the UIButton to show a title beneath? The other problem I'm having is when I set the alignment of the button in IB (in the Control section) it only changes the alignment for the default state not the highlighted state. Can anyone give me some pointers here that would be great thanks!

rc

Answer (score 1):

Putting the UIButton inside a UIBarButtonItem is the best way I've found to do it.  Just set the text for the button and it should show up fine.  When manipulating the positioning, remember you're manipulating the position of the UIBarButtonItem and not the UIButton.  Hope that helps!